# Picking a collection for my data

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have to load and use my data from a db. The data is represented like this:

```
group_id    term
1           hello
1           world
1           bye
2           foo
2           bar

etc.
```

What is a good C# collection to load and use this data?

Comment: The choice of data structure is highly dependent on how you want to use the data, in addition to the data itself.  Will you be modifying the collection frequently?  Will you be searching for specific items often, or will you generally be going through every item in most cases?  How much data will you have (different data structures scale differently).  Is the memory consumed an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

var dict.Add(1, new List<string> { "hello", "world", "bye" });
var dict.Add(2, new List<string> { "foo", "bar" });
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you have to do with the collection but it seems like [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) is a good candidate in case you need to group by group_id.

If your data is in a datatable:

```
var lookup = table.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(row => row.Field<int>("group_id"));
```

and then access the groups the following way:

```
foreach (var group in lookup)
{
  int groupID = group.Key;
  IEnumerable<DataRow> groupRows = group;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends very strongly on what you need to do with your data.

If you just need to list your data, create a class which holds the data and use a `List<Vocable>`.

```
public class Vocable
{
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
}

List<Vocable> vocables;
```

If you need to look up all terms belonging to a group, use a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` using the group id as key and a list of terms as value.

If you need to look up the group a term belongs to, use a `Dictionary<string, int>` using the term as key and the group id as value.

Answer (score 0):

To load and save data from and to a DB you can use the DataSet/DataTable/DataRow classes. 
Look at DataAdapter etc. depends on your database server (MySQL, MsSQL, ...)

if you want to work with objects i suggest you the ORMs EntityFramework (Microsoft) or SubSonic.
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo

with an ORM you can use LINQ Queries like this:

```
    // Define a query that returns all Department  
    // objects and course objects, ordered by name.
    var departmentQuery = from d in schoolContext.Departments.Include("Courses")
                      orderby d.Name
                      select d;
```